# How to select between/before/after dates in MySQL conditionally?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and would like to get rows that will fit a specific condition.

Say I have this row:

```
id start_date end_date
 3 2020-04-02 NULL
```

And in my web app UI, I have this calendar:

[image]

When you check the table fields, you'll see a `start_date` and an `end_date`. An `end_date` can be null meaning it has no end.

Getting back to the table, I want to get rows by passing `startDates` and `endDates` from UI. The `startDate` will be `March 29` and `endDate` will be `May 9` based on the calendar view.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM slots WHERE start_date <= 2020-03-29 AND (end_date >= 2020-05-09 OR end_date IS NULL)
```

With the code above, I'm not getting any data. It's clearly because the start_date in the table is `2020-04-02` and my query checks for previous date and is equal to startDate from UI.

I also tried (greater than and equal to):

```
SELECT * FROM slots WHERE start_date >= 2020-03-29 AND (end_date >= 2020-05-09 OR end_date IS NULL)
```

And while I got the row, when I click the `next` button in the calendar and switch to May 2020, I'm not getting the row any more. I should get it because the `end_date` is null.

How can I achieve getting the row with `id 3` even when changing months in the UI?

Comment: It seems to me that when you switch to May, the start_date changes and since you are using an "AND" condition then nothing is returned.

Comment: 2020 minus 03 minus 29 equals 1998

Comment: @wobsoriano Strawberry has a trigger finger, and likes to downvote just about anything (including answers).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen haha thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Hi wobsoriano. When writing questions, there's no need to add conversational material, expressions of gratitude, etc. On this platform, that sort of material tends to get edited out, since technical writing is preferred, and we find that brevity makes material easier to read and easier to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find records whose start and end dates overlap with a known range.  This is the overlapping range problem, and you may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM slots
WHERE
    start_date < '2020-05-09' AND
    (end_date > '2020-03-29' OR end_date IS NULL);
```

This says that a valid range *starts* before the end date of your known range, and it *ends* after the start date of your known range, i.e. it lies inside that known range.

Note that date literals in MySQL take single quotes, so you need to fix that as well.

Comment: Ha. Cool! I just tried it and it works. I've played around the previous and next buttons in the calendar and it seems to work pretty well. Thank you! I'll mark as solved in a bit.